# Sync two zimbra server with Imapsync consume a lot of space on destination server

Tags: email, server, zimbra

I'm moving mailbox data from the old zimbra server (oldmail.domain.com) to the new zimbra server (newmail.domain.com) using Imapsync.
I use the following command:

```
imapsync --nofoldersizes --skipsize --fast --nosyncacls --syncinternaldates --host1 oldmail.domain.com --user1 user@domain.com --authuser1 admin --password1 password1 --ssl1 --host2 newmail.domain.com --user2 user@domain.com --authuser2 admin --password2 password2 --ssl2
```

Why when on a new server, mailbox data requires a lot of hard disk space? The old server is under 100GB, the new server is more than 200GB. Meanwhile, the mailbox data that is moved is the same. I check the inbox of each account, there are no duplicate emails.

Why did it happen? If there is a duplication, how do I check the duplication? And how do I delete the duplicated mailbox data?

Answer (score 0):

maybe there are some saved searches or shared folders in your account?

Answer (score 0):

Setelah bertanya ke beberap forum, akhirnya saya mendapatkan jawaban.

Imapsync reads email as a separate object. So if an email is sent and cc to 10 accounts, imapsync will store as many as 10 emails, thus causing greater storage consumption.

In zimbra, there is a zmdedupe command which is executed in zimbra user mode. This command will make these emails saved only once, and will create a link to access them. So that it can save more storage

```
#su - zimbra
$zmdedupe start
```

We can see the status of this process by typing the command

```
zmdedupe status
```

From this command too, we can know how much storage can be saved.